# Why timezone inside unittest in Django is different from timezone in view?

Tags: django, django-settings, django-unittest, django-timezone

I'm using TestCase.client to test my views. And when I call `timezone.now()` from **test case**, i get 2015-11-17 07:48:26.826661+**00:00**, but when I call

```
   start = timezone.make_aware(datetime.strptime(
        date_text + ' ' + time,
        '%y/%m/%d %H:%M'
    ))
```

from **view** I get 2015-11-17 07:36:00+**02:00**.

How to make them use the same timezone?

I'm running using `./manage.py test --settings=www.tests_settings` and `www/tests_settings.py` contains following:

```
from .settings import *

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    }
}

USE_TZ = True
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Kiev'


>>> django.__version__
'1.8.4'
>>> pytz.__version__
'2015.7'
>>> sys.version
'3.4.3 (default, Mar 26 2015, 22:03:40) \n[GCC 4.9.2]'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I see. [`make_aware`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.make_aware) returns time in default time zone, and [`now`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.now) - in UTC. And to get local current time, I need to do `timezone.localtime(timezone.now())`.

But documentation recommends to deal with time and timezones like with text and encodings - store everything in UTC (unicode) and convert only when receiving or giving it to user.